# Generating all combinations and permutations of a set of symbols

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

I am new to Python and want to have a "pythonic" coding style from the very beginning. Following is a piece of codes I wrote to generate all combinations and permutations of a set of symbols, e.g. `abc` or `123`.  I mainly seek for suggestions on code style but comments on other aspects of codes are also welcome.

```
import random as rd
import math as m
def permutationByRecursion(input, s, li):
    if len(s) == len(input):
        li.append(s)
    for i in range(len(input)):
        if input[i] not in s:
            s+=input[i]
            permutationByRecursion(input, s, li)
            s=s[0:-1]

def combinationByRecursion(input, s, idx, li):
    for i in range(idx, len(input)):
        s+=input[i]
        li.append(s)
        print s, idx
        combinationByRecursion(input, s, i+1, li)
        s=s[0:-1]

def permutationByIteration(input):
    level=[input[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(input)):
        nList=[]
        for item in level:
            nList.append(item+input[i])
            for j in range(len(item)):
                nList.append(item[0:j]+input[i]+item[j:])
        level=nList
    return nList

def combinationByIteration(input):
    level=['']
    for i in range(len(input)):
        nList=[]
        for item in level:
            nList.append(item+input[i])
        level+=nList
    return level[1:]



res=[]
#permutationByRecursion('abc', '', res)
combinationByRecursion('abc', '', 0, res)
#res=permutationByIteration('12345')
print res
print combinationByIteration('abc')
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, python has permutations and combinations in itertools package in stdlib.

Comment: @blufox, i am aware of it,  just wrote the program for practice.

Comment: @pegasus, I know blufox and cat_baxter pointed out itertools and I assume you've seen it but for anybody else [the python docs contain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) code samples for both permutation and combination

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small change, In python, it is more idiomatic to use generators to generate items rather than to create lists fully formed. So,

```
def combinationG(input):
    level=['']
```

You could directly enumerate on each character here.

```
    for v in input:
        nList=[]
        for item in level:
            new = item + v
```

Yield is the crux of a generator.

```
            yield new
            nList.append(new)
        level+=nList
```

Using it

```
print list(combinationG("abc"))
```

Note that if you want access to both index and value of a container you can use `for i,v in enumerate(input)`

Here is the recursive implementation of permutation. Notice that we have to yield on the value returned by the recursive call too.

```
def permutationG(input, s):
    if len(s) == len(input): yield s
    for i in input:
        if i in s: continue
        s=s+i
        for x in permutationG(input, s): yield x
        s=s[:-1]


print list(permutationG('abc',''))
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use the standard modules :)

```
import itertools
for e in itertools.permutations('abc'):
    print(e)
```

Comment: thanks, I am aware of it. Just wrote it for practicing python